# Failed to create Jar File

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.

> Failed to create Jar file C:\Users\Mahjur - Coding.gradle\caches\jars-8\ec50ce4709fd95f8ed96c3a048d9b515\databinding-compiler-common-4.1.0.jar.

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Hello all, every time I try to run my code, I am getting this error. Others I know are able to run this just fine, It seems that I'm the only one dealing with this issue. Any solution? I am new to this all, so please be detailed when giving any explanations.

Answer (score 0):

you have to put databinding-compiler-common-4.1.0.jar file in  C:\Users\Mahjur - Coding.gradle\caches\jars-8\ec50ce4709fd95f8ed96c3a048d9b515\ folder it will solve problem.

In my case I was not knowing exact jar name so created dummy file still it have worked.

For me error was like below `GradleException: Failed to create Jar file /root/.gradle/caches/jars-8/da1fb602f5e9c4589f7a774fa11d9312/bin.jar`

Solution was : `touch /root/.gradle/caches/jars-8/da1fb602f5e9c4589f7a774fa11d9312/bin.jar`

If it will help.